# User Does not Exist Oracle SQL developer

Tags: sql, oracle, function

Forgive me if this is a simple fix, I am quite new to SQL, just started learning it on Tuesday. So I am experimenting with functions and made a simple one to test it out such as

```
CREATE FUNCTION CHINOOKHW.AddPara(@a1 int, @b2 int)
RETURN INT
BEGIN AS
  DECLARE @C3 INT = SUM(A1, B2)
  RETURN @C3
END
GO
CHINOOKHW.AddPara(1, 2);
```

but I get the error

```
Error report -
ORA-01435: user does not exist
01435. 00000 -  "user does not exist"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

I have already defined my user as

```
CREATE USER chinookhw
IDENTIFIED BY p4ssw0rd;
```

And while I know this is normally bad practice, I even gave my user all access like

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES to chinookhw IDENTIFIED BY p4ssw0rd;
```

I am not sure if this is relevant but I a connected to the chinook database from 
https://chinookdatabase.codeplex.com/

and I made another connection from the system database with the lines

```
GRANT DBA TO chinook;
GRANT DBA TO chinookhw;
commit;
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? I've been at this for hours with no fix. Thank you in advance

Comment: This is not Oracle syntax... Start from the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/create_function.htm#LNPLS01370)

Comment: Where in the [Oracle PL/SQL reference](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/toc.htm) did you find that syntax?

Comment: Are you connected as CHINOOKHW when you try and create the function? (As others have pointed out, it's not valid PL/SQL syntax, and it will throw up syntax errors if you were able to get to the point where it would attempt compilation.)

Comment: @Aleksej The function isn't oracle syntax? I figured my code would not work anyway but I was going to learn the proper way later. I apologize for that. Is that what is causing my error?

Comment: @Boneist, yeah I'm connected as CHINOOKHW

Comment: Not Oracle at all. The link I gave contains some examples to look

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try the following - note how it's not specifying the user that the function is to be created under. Note also how the syntax is PL/SQL and not T-SQL or whatever it is you wrote yours in:

```
CREATE FUNCTION AddPara(a1 integer, b2 integer)
RETURN INTeger
AS
BEGIN
  return A1 + B2;
END;
/
```

Comment: I meant to add: it would be interesting to see which user owns that function, which you can see by running: `select * from dba_objects where object_name = 'ADDPARA';`.

Comment: Actually I figured it out. My file has over 100 lines of code and had another function defined by another user which didnt exist.  i feel so stupid.

Comment: There isn't a developer alive in the world who hasn't made a similar mistake! Myself included \*whistles\*